# How to retrieve a batch of kafka avro messages with message headers for acknowledgement using Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using spring-cloud-stream 4.0.2 with spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka 4.0.2 and spring-cloud-stream-schema 2.2.1.RELEASE.

I'm trying to configure Spring Cloud Stream Consumer for Kafka Avro topic with confluent schema and **manual** AckMode. It works correctly when I'm trying to retrieve messages one by one (I get a Message object with deserialized avro object) but when consuming a whole batch, the payload is empty.

Working setup with messages one by one:
**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: <brokerURL>
          replication-factor: 1
          consumer-properties:
            schema.registry.url: <schemaRegistryURL>
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            specific.avro.reader: true
        bindings:
          input-in-0:
            consumer:
              ack-mode: MANUAL
      default:
        group: <consumerGroup>
      bindings:
        input-in-0:
          destination: <inputKafkaTopic>
          content-type: application/*+avro
```

**MainConsumer.java**

```
@Component
public class MainConsumer {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<MyAvroObject>> input() {
        return event -> {
            log.info("Consumed event: {}", event.getPayload()); // THIS PROPERLY RETURNS DESERIALIZED PAYLOAD
            Acknowledgment ack = event.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
            ack.acknowledge();
        };
    }
}
```

Setup with batch processing that doesn't work correctly - Payload is empty.
**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: <brokerURL>
          replication-factor: 1
          consumer-properties:
            schema.registry.url: <schemaRegistryURL>
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            specific.avro.reader: true
            max-poll-records: 500
        bindings:
          input-in-0:
            consumer:
              ack-mode: MANUAL
      default:
        group: <consumerGroup>
      bindings:
        input-in-0:
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true
          destination: <inputKafkaTopic>
          content-type: application/*+avro
```

**MainConsumer.java**

```
@Component
public class MainConsumer {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<List<MyAvroObject>>> input() {
        return event -> {
            log.info("Consumed event: {}", event.getPayload()); // THIS RETURNS EMPTY LIST
            Acknowledgment ack = event.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
            ack.acknowledge();
        };
    }
}
```

I also tried variation with Consumer<List<Message>> but that just creates a ClassCastException.

How to make it work with batch messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out to make it work for batch processing, I needed to turn on native decoding in Spring Cloud Stream binding. Not sure why that is, so if anyone knows answer to that question, please comment :)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: <brokerURL>
          replication-factor: 1
          consumer-properties:
            schema.registry.url: <schemaRegistryURL>
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            specific.avro.reader: true
            max-poll-records: 500
        bindings:
          input-in-0:
            consumer:
              ack-mode: MANUAL
      default:
        group: <consumerGroup>
      bindings:
        input-in-0:
          consumer:
            use-native-decoding: true
            batch-mode: true
          destination: <inputKafkaTopic>
          content-type: application/*+avro
```

Comment: I spend hours on this, then I decided to post a SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76941303/consuming-batches-of-avro-events-in-reactive-functional-bindings-payload-is-los and finally, I found a solution here. Thanks for showing this!