# Consuming batches of Avro events in reactive functional bindings. Payload is lost when using type parameter instead of wildcard

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to consume a batch of Avro events in the Spring Boot application. Because of business requirements, I have to acknowledge the batch manually, therefore I need to have an incoming batch wrapped in the `Message` and access to its headers. I created the following binding:

```java
@Bean
public Function<Flux<Message<List<MyAvroEvent>>>, Mono<Void>> consumeAvroEvents() {
    return flux -> flux
        .concatMap(events -> {
           Acknowledgment acknowledgment = events.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
           List<MyAvroEvent> events = events.getPayload(); // this list is empty
           // save event in DB
           // acknowledge in case of no timeout-related exceptions 
           // otherwise do not acknowledge
        })
        .then();
}
```

I noticed that `events.getPayload()` is empty which is incorrect. When I got rid of the type parameter and use wildcard the payload is not empty:

```java
@Bean
public Function<Flux<Message<?>>, Mono<Void>> consumeAvroEvents() {
return flux -> flux
        .concatMap(events -> {
           Message<List<MyAvroEvents>> typedEvents = (Message<List<MyAvroEvents>>) events;
           Acknowledgment acknowledgment = typedEvents.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
  
           List<MyAvroEvent> events = typedEvents.getPayload(); // this list is NOT empty
           // save event in DB
           // acknowledge in case of no timeout-related exceptions 
           // otherwise do not acknowledge
        })
        .then();
}
```

I debugged the first version `Function<Flux<Message<List<MyAvroEvent>>>, Mono<Void>>` and I can see that the payload is lost under [SimpleFunctionRegistry.java#L1256](https://github.com/corneil/spring-cloud-function/blob/7aa56b977eb66b2b9b063c249a8f1278381515ae/spring-cloud-function-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/context/catalog/SimpleFunctionRegistry.java#L1256). Is it a bug or only the wildcard parameter is allowed in consuming batches? The [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/4.0.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_example_setting_ackmode_to_manual_and_relying_on_manual_acknowledgement) mentions only wildcard actually.

Versions:

- spring-cloud-stream:4.0.2
- spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:4.0.2
- spring-cloud-function-core:4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `use-native-decoding: true` makes it work as described under
[How to retrieve a batch of kafka avro messages with message headers for acknowledgement using Spring Cloud Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76236131/how-to-retrieve-a-batch-of-kafka-avro-messages-with-message-headers-for-acknowle)

With that, I can use the type parameter:

```java
Function<Flux<Message<List<MyAvroEvent>>>, Mono<Void>> consumeAvroEvents()
```